# ¿Cómo hago para agregar una cola FIFO de peticiones? La siguiente petición tiene que esperar a la anterior

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos, queue

Mi duda es como puedo hacer una cola de peticiones o procesos en python.
El objetivo es crear un programa el cual muestre un menú en todo momento para agregar más procesos o para finalizar el programa. Esto mientras se **ejecutan** los otros procesos que el usuario introdujo.
Osea que en todo momento el usuario tiene que poder ingresar nuevos procesos y que estos se agreguen a la cola de espera de que los demas terminen para ahora seguir ellos.

Cada proceso que se agrega tiene un `id`, operacion que realiza, usuario y tiempo que llevará el proceso para terminar. Y al darle a *finalizar programa* este tiene que esperar a que la cola de peticiones termine para poder salir.

Lo que no consigo es agregar una cola que se realice en segundo plano y a su vez ésta realmente espere a que el proceso anterior termine de ejecutarse.

Tengo un código en el cual he estado intentando agregar la cola pero no lo consigo. Al agregar un nuevo proceso con un tiempo de ejecucion de 1 minuto y despues agregar otro de 1 segundo, este no espera a que el de 1 minuto termine y acaba antes el de 1 segundo. **¿Como hago para que este segundo proceso espere a su proceso anterior?**

Este cédigo es con el que he estado probando. Actualmente no tiene agregado el código para hacer la cola.

```
from yachalk import chalk
import queue
import threading
import time
ids = 0

def agregarProceso():
    user = input(chalk.gray("Ingresa el usuario que deseas establecer:   "))
    nombreOperacion = input(chalk.blue("¿Que operacion desea realizar?:   "))
    tiempoProceso = int(input(chalk.blue("¿Cuanto tiempo llevara?:   ")))

    def proceso():
        time.sleep(tiempoProceso)
        print(chalk.green(f"\n Ha finalizado tu proceso {nombreOperacion} con iD #{ids}"))
        print(chalk.green(f"Tiempo transcurrido de {tiempoProceso} segundos"))
        print(chalk.green(f"De parte de {user}\n"))

    th1 = threading.Thread(target=proceso)
    th1.start()

while True:

    entradaMenu = input(chalk.blue("Selecciona una opcion: \n Agregar proceso // 1 // \n Cerrar programa // 2 // \n "))
    if entradaMenu == "1":
        ids += 1
        agregarProceso()
    if entradaMenu == "2":
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo te falta hacer un `th1.join()` después del `th1.start()`.

Esta función detiene la ejecución del programa principal hasta que el thread `th1` termine.

Demo

```
import threading
import time
import random

def agregarProceso(ids):
    user = "Juanito"
    nombreOperacion = "Esperar"
    tiempoProceso = random.randint(10, 30)

    print(f"Proceso {ids} tomara {tiempoProceso} segundos")

    def proceso():
        time.sleep(tiempoProceso)
        print(f"Ha finalizado tu proceso {nombreOperacion} con iD #{ids}")
        print(f"Tiempo transcurrido de {tiempoProceso} segundos")
        print(f"De parte de {user}\n")

    th1 = threading.Thread(target=proceso)
    th1.start()
    th1.join()

for ids in range(5):
    agregarProceso(ids)
```

produce:

```
Proceso 0 tomara 14 segundos
Ha finalizado tu proceso Esperar con iD #0
Tiempo transcurrido de 14 segundos
De parte de Juanito

Proceso 1 tomara 17 segundos
Ha finalizado tu proceso Esperar con iD #1
Tiempo transcurrido de 17 segundos
De parte de Juanito

Proceso 2 tomara 27 segundos
Ha finalizado tu proceso Esperar con iD #2
Tiempo transcurrido de 27 segundos
De parte de Juanito

Proceso 3 tomara 20 segundos
Ha finalizado tu proceso Esperar con iD #3
Tiempo transcurrido de 20 segundos
De parte de Juanito

Proceso 4 tomara 23 segundos
Ha finalizado tu proceso Esperar con iD #4
Tiempo transcurrido de 23 segundos
De parte de Juanito

Fin

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Funciona bien para esperar a que el proceso termine, pero me pregunto si hay alguna forma de hacer que pueda introducir el usuario otro proceso mientras se ejecuta uno anterior y este que introdujo despues espere a que el primero termine de ejecutarse para ahora seguir el. no se si me explico bien. gracias por su atencion.

Comment: Esa es una pregunta distinta. Puedes hacer una nueva pregunta.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda